# Swapping rows between columns within dataframe for multiple dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have a dataframe which looks like following,

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(
        [['chr1',2,1,'+',0.1,'NA','TSS1'],
        ['chr2',3,4,'-',0.03,'NA','TSS2'],
        ['chr3',7,6,'+',0.7,'NA','TSS3']], 
        columns = ('CHR', 'start', 'end','Strand','Peak','Ratio','Annotation')
    )
foo
    CHR start   end Strand  Peak    Ratio   Annotation
0   chr1    2   1   +   0.10    NA  TSS1
1   chr2    3   4   -   0.03    NA  TSS2
2   chr3    7   6   +   0.70    NA  TSS3
```

And I am aiming to swap between the column start and End, ie if the column start is greater than column end then I need it to swap its position and keep the rest of columns intact or just as it is.

something like this,

```
def fun(x):
   if df['start']> df['End']
print df[['CHR','end','start','Strand','Peak','Ratio','Annotation']]
   else
  return df
```

The above function doesn't work as I needed.
At the end, I need a dataframe,

```
    CHR   start  end    Strand  Peak    Ratio   Annotation
0   chr1    1   2   +   0.10    NA  TSS1
1   chr2    3   4   -   0.03    NA  TSS2
2   chr3    6   7   +   0.70    NA  TSS3
```

Any help or better suggestions would be great. Also, I have large multiple data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simplier is:

```
foo[['start','end']] = foo[['start','end']].apply(np.sort, axis=1)
print (foo)
    CHR  start  end Strand  Peak Ratio Annotation
0  chr1      1    2      +  0.10    NA       TSS1
1  chr2      3    4      -  0.03    NA       TSS2
2  chr3      6    7      +  0.70    NA       TSS3
```

Another solution with `min` and `max`:

```
df1 = foo[['start','end']]
foo['start'] = df1.min(axis=1)
foo['end'] =   df1.max(axis=1)
print (foo)
    CHR  start  end Strand  Peak Ratio Annotation
0  chr1      1    2      +  0.10    NA       TSS1
1  chr2      3    4      -  0.03    NA       TSS2
2  chr3      6    7      +  0.70    NA       TSS3
```

Solution with condition and [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but need [numpy.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) for repeating `mask` for each column:

```
b = foo['start'] < foo['end']
foo[['start','end']] = np.where(np.column_stack([b,b]),
                                foo[['start','end']],
                                foo[['end','start']])
print (foo)
    CHR  start  end Strand  Peak Ratio Annotation
0  chr1      1    2      +  0.10    NA       TSS1
1  chr2      3    4      -  0.03    NA       TSS2
2  chr3      6    7      +  0.70    NA       TSS3
```

If need custom function `apply` is not necessary:

```
def fun(foo):
    b = foo['start'] < foo['end']
    foo[['start','end']] = np.where(np.column_stack([b,b]), 
                                    foo[['start','end']], 
                                    foo[['end','start']])
    return foo

print (fun(foo))
    CHR  start  end Strand  Peak Ratio Annotation
0  chr1      1    2      +  0.10    NA       TSS1
1  chr2      3    4      -  0.03    NA       TSS2
2  chr3      6    7      +  0.70    NA       TSS3
```

Comment: No, The swapping should be based on a condition not just changing the positions of columns. If the column 'end' is smaller than the column 'start' then swap those rows and otherwise keep it as it is. Also the above command is not working with the bigger dataframes

Comment: Also is it possible to make it as a function where I can use it to df.apply(func)

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is possible, but not so easy. But give me some time.

Comment: Actually No there is a problem its throwing key error for column end

Comment: Hmmm, maybe some whitespace? Check `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143306/discussion-between-user1017373-and-jezrael).